# show only some top portion of image in flutter

Tags: android, ios, image, flutter

In my app i want show image in some portion of screen and after click on read more image size needs to decrease and show only top portion of image

this is normal condition (Pic 1)

[image]

when user click read more I want to show only some top portion of the image like this (Pic 2)

[image]

Here is my code

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:4.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.asset(       //image
                        "images/background.png",
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.33,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      ),
                    Align(            // for topleft home icon
                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                      child: Container(
                        width: 40, height: 40,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                        child: IconButton(
                          icon: new SvgPicture.asset("images/done_icon.svg",height: 30,width: 30,),
                          onPressed: () {},
                        ),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          color: Colors.black12
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                ]
                ),
```

I want design as pic 2 after click read more button just tell me want changes is required in image and I will put in read more text onclick event

Answer (score 5):

One way you can do is like this.

```
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  double bannerHeight = 100;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Image.network(
            'https://images.pexels.com/photos/235986/pexels-photo-235986.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500',
            height: bannerHeight,
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter, 
            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 30),
        FlatButton(
          child: Text('Read More'),
          onPressed: () {
            setState((){
              if(bannerHeight == 100){
                bannerHeight = 200;
              }
              else{
                bannerHeight = 100;
              }
            });
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

See on dartpad - https://dartpad.dev/558fc0badbbc444d418b76fc01aa45cd